# Searching a list for values SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, list, count, concatenation

I Have one list that is instantiated by the following:

```
SELECT 
ddlIRC
FROM CSART.DBO.tblMaintenance
```

Within this selection is a list of values. These values are concatenated and stored in other fields in a separate table. E.g. In the above list their may be row values like "Pharmacy" or "CFC" or "KFC".
In the Below columns there may be values stored in each row like "Select Multiple: Pharmacy,CFC,KFC". I need a total count for each of the values found in the above list, that are stored in the below columns.

```
SELECT
ICP1
ICP2
ICP3
ICP4
FROM CSART.DBO.FllwUp

ICP1
---------
Pharmacy
NULL
Select Multiple:SRH,CD,MOH
```

I have some experience in SQL, but this is giving me a pretty bad headache.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please attach your sample data returned by those queries. Also, tag your DBMS. Answers can be database specific.

Comment: I guess that it is sql server due to the `.DBO.` in the query